# Url argument with Django

Tags: python, django, url

I'm having some problem with my url in Django (1.9)

Tried many way to solve it, but still the same type of error

```
Reverse for 'elus' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'council': u'CFVU'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['elus/(?P<council>[A-B]+)$']
```

The actual code is this :

View :

```
class RepresentativeView(ListView):
    model = Representative
    template_name= 'lea/elus.html'
    context_object_name = 'represents'

    def get_queryset(self, council):

        return Representative.objects.filter(active=True).filter(council=council).order_by(order)
```

url :

```
url(r'^elus/(?P<council>[A-B]+)$', views.RepresentativeView.as_view(), name='elus'),
```

Template :

```
{% url 'elus' council='CFVU' %}
```

I've tried with `**kwargs` and other things. It work with `**kwargs` in another function with `<pk>` in url, and my query is based on the `id`. But here, with a string I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have `[A-B]` will only match the letters A and B.

If you only want to match uppercase letters you could do:

```
url(r'^elus/(?P<council>[A-Z]+)$
```

Or, a common approach is to use `[\w-]+`, which will match upper case A-Z, lowercase a-z, digits 0-9, underscores, and hyphens:

```
url(r'^elus/(?P<council>[\w-]+)$
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the waste of time ... This error was really stupid error.